# FragmentPagerAdapter in a Fragment get error MainActivity must impliement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have android application with navigation drawer with menu like Videos, Graphs, Share. Each of menu linked to fragment. In Graphs I want to show tabs layout but while implementing ViewPager with fragment for each tab It's raise an exception MainActivity must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener.
Here is logcat errors

> 10-27 00:12:43.560 31450-31450/com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer
>   I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to
>   using android:theme instead. 10-27 00:12:43.626
>   31450-31450/com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer D/AndroidRuntime:
>   Shutting down VM
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException:                com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.activity.MainActivity@a8ce577 must
>   implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.fragment.HappinessFragment.onAttach(HappinessFragment.java:77)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1043)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:838)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:861)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:719)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.onMeasure(AppBarLayout.java:218)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1085)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
>                                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18809)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1228)
>                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1464)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.d

This is GraphFragment.java

```
package com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.R;
import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.other.TabsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link GraphFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link GraphFragment newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class GraphFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private String[] tabs = {"Happiness", "Anger", "Surprice",
    "Neutral", "Sadness"};


    public GraphFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View inflatedView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(tab_name));
        }
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return inflatedView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

This is TabsPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.other;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.fragment.AngerFragment;
import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.fragment.HappinessFragment;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new HappinessFragment();
            case 1:
                // Games fragment activity
                return new AngerFragment();
            case 2:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new HappinessFragment();
            case 3:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new AngerFragment();
            case 4:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new HappinessFragment();
            case 5:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new AngerFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 6;
    }

}
```

And This is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.R;
import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.fragment.GraphFragment;
import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.fragment.HomeFragment;
import com.example.dp.facialemotionalyzer.fragment.VideoFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GraphFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private View navHeader;
    private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
    private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_VIDEO = "video";
    private static final String TAG_GRAPH = "graph";
    private static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
    private String[] activityTitles;
    private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private int navItemIndex = 0;
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });

        setUpNavigationView();
        if (savedInstanceState == null && checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
        }
    }

    private void loadHomeFragment(){
        selectNavMenu();
        setToolbarTitle();
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null){
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            toggleFab();
            return;
        }

        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        if(mPendingRunnable != null){
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        toggleFab();

        drawer.closeDrawers();

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private Fragment getHomeFragment(){
        switch (navItemIndex){
            case 0:
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                return homeFragment;
            case 1:
                VideoFragment videoFragment = new VideoFragment();
                return videoFragment;
            case 2:
                GraphFragment graphFragment = new GraphFragment();
                return graphFragment;
            default:
                return new HomeFragment();
        }
    }

    private void setToolbarTitle(){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
    }

    private void selectNavMenu(){
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }
    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_video:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_VIDEO;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_graph:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_GRAPH;
                        break;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }

        // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
        // when user is in other fragment than home
        if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
            // checking if user is on other navigation menu
            // rather than home
            if (navItemIndex != 0) {
                navItemIndex = 0;
                CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                loadHomeFragment();
                return;
            }
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        // show menu only when home fragment is selected
        if (navItemIndex == 0) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        }

        // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
        if (navItemIndex == 3) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        // user is in notifications fragment
        // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
        if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // user is in notifications fragment
        // and selected 'Clear All'
        if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // show or hide the fab
    private void toggleFab() {
        if (navItemIndex == 0)
            fab.show();
        else
            fab.hide();
    }

    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post code of HappinessFragment.